# GCD is homogenous

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Hi I would like to ask whether this is a liable solution, $(a,b)$ meaning the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$:

Show that if $a>0$ then $(ab,ac)=a(b,c)$.

Assume that $(b,c)=n$ then $n$ is expressible as the smallest positive linear combination of $b$ and $c$. So we have
     $$
  n=bk+cl
  $$
     for some $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Multiplying by $a$ on both sides we get
     $$
  an=abk+acl
  $$
     since $a>0$ this is still the smallest positive linear combination of $ab$ and $ac$ and therefore $an$ is the greatest common divisor of $ab$ and $ac$ which is the desired result.

Comment: It is missing the argument of why $an$ is the smallest. You can try proving it directly by the definition: $an$ is a common divisor of $ab$ and $ac$. If $d$ divides $ab$ and $ac$. Let $d=d_1d_2$, where $d_1=(a,d)$. Then $d_2$ divides $b$ and $c$. Therefore it divides $n=(b,c)$. Hence $d$ divides $an$.

Comment: I'd used the definition of gcd (instead of ''smallest'' linear combination).

Comment: I'd say that GCD is *homogenous*  instead of *multiplicative*, which has a different meaning in number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your argument is fine. However, I would put a little bit more effort in justifying

> *since $a>0$ this is still the smallest positive linear combination of $ab$ and $ac$*

For instance, derive a contradiction from this: suppose we had $\tilde{k},\tilde{l}\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. the linear combination $ab\tilde{k}+ac\tilde{l}$ was positive and less than $abk+acl$. That is, $ab\tilde{k}+ac\tilde{l}<abk+acl$ or which amounts to the same thing, $a(b\tilde{k}+c\tilde{l})<a(bk+cl)$. Why can't this happen?